# Англо(-)католик

Tags: слитно-дефис

Требуется ли дефис в слове «англо(-)католик»?

Answer (score 1):

> Термины англокатолицизм (Anglo-Catholicism), англиканский католицизм
> (Anglican Catholicism) и католическое англиканство (Catholic
> Anglicanism) относятся ***к людям, убеждениям и практикам*** в рамках
> англиканства, которые подчёркивают католическое наследие и
> идентичность различных англиканских церквей.
>
> Термин «англо-католический» (anglo-Catholic) был придуман в начале XIX
> века, хотя движения, подчеркивающие католическую природу англиканства,
> уже существовали.

[https://wiki2.org/ru/Англокатолицизм](https://wiki2.org/ru/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)